# Is there a way to use the dotnet format command to undo a rule?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dotnet-format

Typically the `dotnet format --diagnostics CODE` command is used to apply a format in a project or a solution. However, is there a way to reverse that action?

For example, I prefer:

```
var sub = value.Substring(1, value.Length - 2);
```

over

```
var sub = value[1..^1];
```

I added the following in the `.editorconfig` file

```
csharp_style_prefer_index_operator = false : warning
dotnet_diagnostic.IDE0057.severity = warning
```

Now how can convert any `value[1..^1];` syntax to `value.Substring(1, value.Length - 2)` using the `dotnet format` command?

I tried the following command

```
dotnet format --diagnostics IDE0057 --severity warn
```

It did not convert the syntax.

Comment: Have you tried dropping the `: warning` part from  `csharp_style_prefer_index_operator = false` ?

Comment: @MikeNakis yes I tried that. Same result.

Comment: Try using ReSharper